# Javascript async/await and Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

My understanding of `async/await` is fairly simplistic: if you `await` functions which return a promise they will return the value passed into the `resolve` callback. A function containing an `await` keyword must be marked `async`. If that isn't true, that's where my understanding is faulty.

Either I'm being super-unobservant, or the following behaviour proves my understanding to be incorrect:

```
async function mySynchroniser(promise) {
  return await promise;
}

const stuff = mySynchroniser(new Promise(function (resolve) {
  resolve('stuff');
}));

console.log(stuff);
```

I would expect the output to be `stuff`, but the actual output is `Promise {<pending>}`. When I expand the Promise in the console log, it has resolved to the value 'stuff', which should surprise nobody.

Please help me find the flaw in my understanding or observational skills.

Comment: `mySynchroniser` now returns a promise you'd need to `await` too.

Comment: An async function always returns a promise itself.

Comment: You can't expect a result in a synchronous manner from an asynchronously invoked procedure.